# R: Where is the mistake: if statement over multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, sapply

I have the following data table, with columns of class "character"

```
dt <- data.table(V1 = c("0", "1", "1/2", "4"), V2 = c("1/2", "3/4", "", ""))
```

I want to have all the fractions over at the second column and in the first column natural numbers only. I came up with the following solution:

```
if(str_detect(new$V1, "/")){
  new$V2 <- new$V1
  new$V1 <- 0
}
```

and also tried to embed it in a function and finish it with with `sapply`.

```
FractionExtraction <- function(x, y) {
  if(str_detect(x, "/")){
  y <- x 
  } else {y <- y}
  y
}

dt$V2  <- sapply(dt$V1, FractionExtraction, dt$V2)
```

I also tried using the %in% inside the if statement, or exchanging the "<-" with a sign of equality, still I would receive the following error

```
Warning message:
In if (str_detect(new$V1, "/")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Ideally, the output would look like this:

```
> dt
   V1  V2
1:  0 1/2
2:  1 3/4
3:  0 1/2
4:  4
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: Is it a problem do you think, to use dplyr on data.table? I went for the other one, simply because I find the semantics more straightforward. For instance, I don't understand well the := sign... The other was easier for me, lets say

Comment: i got it but I was thinking that you need a data.table solution when your data construct is data.table and it is more efficient

Comment: Uses less memory you say? Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just specify the condition in `i` and assign (`:=`) the values for the columns 'V2' and 'V1' to 'V1' and 0

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
dt[str_detect(V1, "/"), c('V2', 'V1') := .(V1, 0)]
dt
#   V1  V2
#1:  0 1/2
#2:  1 3/4
#3:  0 1/2
#4:  4
```

---

In the OP's. code, it is doing an `if/else` is not vectorized and the OP is making amends by looping over 'V1', while the 'y' is still the whole column in `sapply` and this results in getting 4 values in each element of 'V1'.  Instead it can be `Map`, but then the code also needs some changes

---

#### Benchmarks

```
dt1 <- dt[rep(seq_len(.N), 1e7)]
system.time(dt1 %>%  mutate(V2 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "/"), V1, V2),
          V1 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "/"), 0, V1)))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 30.485   2.966  33.506 
system.time(dt1[str_detect(V1, "/"), c('V2', 'V1') := .(V1, 0)])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  5.143   0.689   5.811
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`:

```
dt %>% 
  mutate(V2 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "/"), V1, V2),
         V1 = ifelse(str_detect(V1, "/"), 0, V1))
```

```
  V1  V2
1  0 1/2
2  1 3/4
3  0 1/2
4  4
```